# How to calculate a pandas column based on the previous value in the same column that is calculated?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to achieve the following table, where the values in "md" needs to be calculated :

```
   msotc   md
0      0    0
1      1    1
2      2    3
3      3    7
4      4   15
5      5   31
6      6   63
7      7  127
```

Given:

- The total rows is based on a given value (msotc + 1)
- The first value in column "md" needs to be 0
- The value for row[1] to row[-1] are calculate based in formula: (prev_md * soss) + sopd

Solutions (I think):

- Create a new column with a formula
- Create an empty column "md" with the value 0 on index[0] and calculate the other rows

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

msotc = 7
sopd = 1 # (= not fixed, could be eg. 0.5)
soss = 2 # (= not fixed, could be eg. 1.05)

arr = [np.NaN] * (msotc + 1)
arr[0] = 0

data = {
    "msotc": range(0, msotc + 1, 1),
    "md": arr
}

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=data
)

# df["md"] = (df["md"].shift(1) * soss) + sopd <- This doesn't work
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use math to convert your formula into a geometric series.

```
md[n] = md[n-1]*soss + sopd
```

expressed in terms of `md[0]` and using the formula for the sum of powers:

```
md[n] = md[0]*soss**(n-1) + sopd * (soss**n - 1)/(soss-1)
```

Thus no need to loop, you can vectorize:

```
msotc = 7
sopd = 1
soss = 2
md0 = 0

n = np.arange(msotc+1)
df = pd.DataFrame({'msotc': n, 'md': md0*soss**np.clip(n-1, 0, np.inf) + sopd*(soss**n-1)/(soss-1)})
```

output:

```
   msotc     md
0      0    0.0
1      1    1.0
2      2    3.0
3      3    7.0
4      4   15.0
5      5   31.0
6      6   63.0
7      7  127.0
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine. It is quite easy to understand, just a simple loop.

```
arr = [0] * (msotc + 1)
for i in range(msotc + 1):
    if i == 0:
        continue
    arr[i] = (arr[i - 1] * soss) + sopd
```

Comment: Thanks all for your answer, but I have add some additional info:

- The values sopd and soss are not fixed, they will come in from a range, so a formula cannot contain fixed values. Values can be like: sopd = 0.5 and soss = 1.05
- This table will be created base on another Dataframe with all the different values (over 88million combinations), so this table need to be created as fast as possible. As I understand that vectorization is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
import pandas as pd

msotc = 7
sopd = 1
soss = 2

msotc_vals = []
arr = [0]
for val in range(msotc + 1):
    msotc_vals += [val]
    arr += [arr[-1] * soss + sopd]

data = {"msotc": msotc_vals, "md": arr[:-1]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
```